# ANTLR - The following alternatives can never be matched

Tags: antlr, context-free-grammar

I am unable to understand why this simple grammar -

```
grammar Test;
file    :   ID;
ID  :   .*;
```

leads to this error -

```
Test.g:3:6: The following alternatives can never be matched: 1
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6):

Using `.*` and `.+` at the end of a lexer rule is illegal in ANTLR:

```
ID : .*;       // illegal
ID : 'bar' .*; // illegal
ID : .* 'bar'; // legal
```

In parser rules, this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks!

That seems applicable to ".+" also.

Is there any reason for this restriction within ANTLR? If so, where is it mentioned in the ANTLR documentation? Or, is that just a normal lexer practise?

The same doesn't seem to be applicable for parser rules?

Comment: @user869081, true `.+` is illegal as well, and both `.*` and `.+` _can_ be used in parser rules (edited my answer to include this). Whether this is specific to ANTLR (opposed to other parser generators) or it's a lexer-specific thing in general, I don't know. AFAIK, it's mentioned in Parr's 'Definitive ANTLR Reference' (I'll have a look later on to see if I can find the page).

Comment: Thanks again! I am also working my way through that book. But I can't see where Parr says that? BTW, replacing "." with "('\u0001'.. '\uffff')" doesn't lead to any errors. -Xdbgconversion flag seems to give some information but I am not sure what it means.

Comment: @user869081, the fact that ANTLR makes `.*` and `.+` ungreedy (I believe this can be found in Chapter 4.3, section "Extended BNF rules"), it expects a character _after_ `.*` and `.+`. You may very well be right that this isn't mentioned verbatim like that, but can be implied by the info from "Extended BNF rules". I don't have access to the book at the moment...

Comment: Thanks again! As I re-read these lines with your examples in mind it does seem implied -'Such greedy subrules would match all characters until the end of file. Instead, ANTLR considers them idioms for “Match any symbol until you see what lies beyond the subrule.” ANTLR automatically makes these two subrules nongreedy.' I will be reading that book with a new found respect.